# Keyup event not triggering

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, keyup

It is the HTML Code .I put input for entering key and for pressing.

```
<input type="text" id="filterInput" placeholder="Search names...">
```

What is wrong with this code?

```
let filterInput;//(optional)
let filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');
filterInput.addEventListener('Keyup', filterNames);
function filterNames() {
    console.log(1);
}
```

Comment: javascript is capital sensitve, the right listener is 'keyup' not Keyup, the first line can be deleted, its not optional but actually being reassigned in line 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Keyup" should be "keyup"

```
filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5mfz6o03/